# What are the major texts of Shaivites?

Tags: shiva, bhagavad-gita

Among the major texts of Hinduism, Gita is one of the most accepted texts. It is sung by the Lord Krishna, and in it He says surrender unto Him. 
Do worshippers of Shiva read the Gita as much as Vaishnavas? What are their most important texts?

Comment: Website and magazine published by Shavite monks - http://www.hinduismtoday.com/